# Как правильно написать?

Tags: грамматика

II (О/отделение) Собственной Его Императорского Величества Канцелярии — с какой буквы писать отделение?

Answer (score 1):

Со строчной.
Даже по дореволюционным правилам у вас заглавных многовато: 
*второе отделение Собственной Его Императорского Величества канцелярии*
А сейчас обычно только "Собственной" с заглавной и пишут, правда единых и однозначных рекомендация на этот счет я не видел.